# Custom listview with adding EditText on click on button

Tags: android

I want to add editText on click on button in listview. 
i have created adapter for this to add edittext to listview.
but problem is only one edittext is in Listview. i want to create more than one when click on button.

Please help

Comment: add a function `add()` to your adapter to let it know it needs to return 'one more' next time. And in that function call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. This will trigger the `ListView` to refresh and since your adapter now holds one more it would show another `EditText`.

Comment: As a side note: `EditText` widgets inside `ListView` are a lot of trouble. All the handling of the soft keyboard is messed up. I've tried to make it work and couldn't. My advise: change to `TextView`s in your `ListView` that you can add with a single `EditText` outside of the `ListView`.

Comment: I want to create list of edittext after click on button..please suggest me Best option???adding to listview will be the best option or have to add edittext to linearlayout.

Comment: If you will never have lots of `EditText`s then using a `LinearLayout` that you programmatically add new `EditText`s too will be better. If, however, you could have lots of `EditText`s then this approach will come grinding to a halt. The `ListView` was invented to handle lots of views, but it does not play well with `EditText`s. So, if you need to have lots of items, use the `ListView` but put `TextView`s in it instead of `EditText`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ListView is (should be) backed by some sort of Adapter, which in turn, should be wrapping a Collection of data objects, perhaps a List or String[].

Upon click of the button, you should add the data to the Collection that is wrapped by the Adapter, and then notify the Adapter with `notifyDataSetChanged()`

There's a good tutorial at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: i have done all the work but only one editext is visible at screen.if i scroll then its showing that edittext boxes are adding in the listview. please help

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem, so that we can try to help diagnose your problem.

Comment: edittext< android:id=edit android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:layout_height="wrap_content">        listview to populate <listview android:id=members_list android:layout_width="fill_parent"   android:layout_height="fill_parent"> problem is in layout. all editext are showing if we scroll otheriwse only one is shown at screen